# Convert image data InputStream to string and from this string back to image does not gives the image

Tags: java, image, aem, fileinputstream

Cq5 image component has the binary image data, I require this data to be exposed in an api.

To do this I tried to get the input stream and read it as String.

```
InputStream is = jcrnode.getProperty(JcrConstants.JCR_DATA).getBinary().getStream();

String imageData = jcrnode.getProperty(JcrConstants.JCR_DATA).getString();
```

When trying to write the string to FileOutputStream I dont get the image.

While trying to download the jcr:data manually and open the file image viewer gives the image. 
But when converting this into string and back doesn't work for me. Any suggestions on this.

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to a String?  The string will look like garbage.

Comment: Not sure why this would be done but you can use `String imageData = Base64.encodeBytes(jcrnode.getProperty(JcrConstants.JCR_DATA));` and then use it in `<img alt="Embedded Image" src="<data:image/png;String from above encoding function>" />. That's how you reference embedded images.

Comment: Need to expose image jcr:data with an api to other environment to be consumed, sending the image file. Any suggestions on best way to achieve this. I tried encoding image binary and decode and back to image. Looks tough for me on java 6. Any examples

Comment: Image data can be exposed as base64 encoded string from API. See my comment above on how to do it.

Comment: How to convert the image data as Base64 encoded bytes into the data uri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @i.net was able to solve as per ur suggestions above.

StringBuilder dataUri = New StringBuilder();
dataUri.append("data:image/jpeg;base64");
dataUri.append(StringUtils.newString Utf8(Base64.encodeBase64(imageByteArray,false)));

dataUri.toString() is the string which can be used as embedded images.

Sample html below to render base64 image

```html
<div>
  <p>refer wiki</p>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the crux of it. You have to Base64 encode binaries for HTTP transfer. You can even get the MIME type from DAM properties to make it more generic.